# Twython - How to update status with media url

Tags: python, twitter, twython

In my app, I let users to post to twitter. Now i would like to let them update their status with media.

In `twython.py` i see a method `update_status_with_media` that reads the image from filesystem and uploads to twitter. My images are not in filesystem but on S3 bucket.

How to make this work with S3 bucket urls?

Passing the url in `file_` variable, fails on IO Error, no such file or directory.

Passing StringIO fails on UnicodeDecode Error.

Passing `urllib.urlopen(url).read()` gives `file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str`.

I also tried using `post` method and got 403 Forbidden from twitter api, Error creating status.

**Just Solved it**

Bah, just got it to work, finally! Maybe it will help someone else to save a few hours it cost me.

```
twitter = Twython(
        app_key=settings.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, app_secret=settings.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
        oauth_token=token.token, oauth_token_secret=token.secret
    )
img = requests.get(url=image_obj.url).content
tweet = twitter.post('statuses/update_with_media',
                                 params={'status': msg},
                                 files={'media': (image_obj.url,
                                                  BytesIO(img))})
```

Answer (score 1):

Glad to see you found an answer! There's a similar problem that we handled recently in a **[repo issue](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/issues/191)** - basically, you can do the following with StringIO and passing it directly to twitter.post like you did:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from twython import Twython

t = Twython(...)
img = open('img_url').read()
t.post('/statuses/update_with_media', params = {'status': 'Testing New Status'}, files = {
    'media': StringIO(img)
    # 'media': ('OrThisIfYouWantToNameTheFile.lol', StringIO(img))
})
```

This isn't a direct answer to your question, so I'm not expecting any vote or anything, but figured it's seemingly useful to some people and somewhat related so I'd drop a note.

Comment: actually thats what gave me the idea how to solve it. I saw it during my questing after answer. But i got into problems using `urllib.urlopen().read()` together with `StringIO`, kept failing on `UnicodeDecodeError`. Same happened at first with requests, cos i went for `requests.get(...).text`, when i should have used `requests.get(...).content`.