# Posting a status with video - Twython

Tags: twitter, twython

I'm trying to post a video on behalf of someone through `Twython`.

I have followed the [Twython video upload docs](https://twython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/advanced_usage.html#updating-status-with-video) to achieve it, but it fails with an error on the `upload_video()` method that their [github page](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/issues/422) marked as solved (still happens to me though).

I tried an [SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518689/twython-how-to-update-status-with-media-url) I've found, but it fails also with `TypeError: post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'files'`.

So... Is there any way to achieve that using Twython?

My code:

```
from twython import Twython

twitter = Twython(...)
video = open(video_path, 'rb')
response = twitter.upload_video(media=video, media_type='video/mp4')
twitter.update_status(status='Checkout this cool video!', media_ids=[response['media_id']])
```

Result

```
.
.
response = twitter.upload_video(media=video, media_type='video/mp4')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twython/endpoints.py", line 184, in upload_video
media_chunk.write(data)
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'
```